# perl -V failing on Windows 7, even after uninstall, reinstall, reboot cycle

Tags: perl, windows-7, activeperl, activestate, system-error

I'm running 32-bit Windows 7 Starter on a cheap netbook. I used to do most of my experimental coding in ActiveState Perl but switched to node.js and stopped using Perl for some time.

I had kept my Perl up to date despite not using it so had the latest version, 5.15.3 Build 1604.

Today I found something I wanted try out in Perl but ran into some problems I'd never seen before.

The `perl -V` command in the console would lock up without outputting anything.

I uninstalled Perl, reinstalled, did a Windows update, and rebooted my machine but now I get a system error dialog:

[image: system error]

The dialog is followed by this error in the console:

`Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Win32/Win32.dll' for module Win32: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 191.
  at C:/Perl/lib/ActivePerl/Config.pm line 405.`

Simple things work in perl, such as printing a literal string. ActiveState's package manager tool, ppm, seems to work fine.

I tried doing a "repair" on the installation through the control panel, but this changed nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question I've noticed mentions `perl512.dll`!

For some reason, even though I had uninstalled and reinstalled Perl 5.15.3 something was tying it to Perl version 5.12.X ...

Since ppm was working I tried `ppm upgrade Win32` and got:

`Win32 0.49 (have 0.44)
Downloading Win32-0.49...done
Unpacking Win32-0.49...done
Generating HTML for Win32-0.49...done
Updating files in user area...done
   2 files deleted
   1 file installed
   4 files updated`

`Perl -V` now works in the console. I can't say I really understand what was going on though.